# Some parts of CSS will not render in HTML properly

Tags: html, css, sass

Basically, I converted my .scss files to css with CodeKit and have now made some CSS styles within the application.scss file. I linked the .scss file to my HTML and only some of it is being run. Everything is being rendered except for the border padding. The border is there, the color is there. Not the padding. Any suggestions?

{Sorry if my question format does not fit the standards--it's my first time here}

```css
$dark: #424652;
$light: #9a9da4;
$highlight: #8bc6db;
$border: #e9e9e9;

#main_navigation {
  padding: 2.5em 5%;
  .name {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid $border;
    padding: 0.75em 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $dark;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Guru</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="main_navigation" class="clearfix">
      <a href="#" class="name">Guru</a>
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Articles</a>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <header>
    
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is `em` not `rem` in padding property .

Comment: What does the style inspector show?

Comment: @DavidJawphan — `padding` doesn't forbid the use of `rem` units.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're expecting to see, but perhaps understanding the box model for inline elements will help (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/).